# Can I change Admin Password directly from.... Please HELP!

Tags: admin, password, password-recovery, change-password

Our website developer has not provided us the main Admin ID and Password. so hardly after reading some posts now, I found the admin_user file in the database.

Please find attached screenshot and advice me can I change the  Admin Password directly writing in the Password-Box?[image]

Comment: for magento 1 or Magento 2 ?

Comment: for magento 1 select md5 from dropdown menu

Answer (score 1):

You can try following sql query

```
UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxYourNewPassword', 256), ':xxxxxxx:1') WHERE username = 'admin';
```

Keep `xxxxxxx` as it is in the query.

Alternatively, you can try the command `bin/magento admin:user:create`

For more details on using this command go through https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-admin.html

Comment: This is for M2 only, and dont forget to check the `lock_expires` field also if you've entered multiple wrong passwords already...

Answer (score 0):

no, because the password is hashed.

You can update the password by clicking on sql in the top and executing the following sql command:

```
UPDATE admin_user SET `password` = md5('YOUR_NEW_PASSWORD'), is_active = 1 WHERE `username` = 'YOUR_ADMIN_USERNAME';
```

You should change your password in the Magento backend afterwards again.

Comment: he is already in phpmyadmin admin_user table , just use dropdown menu, select md5 and thats it. but it will work only for magento 1

Answer (score 0):

You can update the password by using Function of MD5 please check below image.

[image]

Comment: Nope.  Doesn't work in M2

Comment: More specifically, M2 requires `SHA2`, and requires a salt...